# Grafana sumarize sum resolution

Tags: grafana, summarize

Grafana 3.1.1 with a whisper backend.

I am trying to use summarize to keep track of how many minutes during the day one if my parameters is set to 1.

Here is the statement that I am using:
summarize(thermostat.living_room.heatstate, '1d', 'sum', false)

It always display much less of a total than expected. To troubleshoot I changed the statement to:
summarize(thermostat.living_room.heatstate, '1h', 'sum', false)

If my time range is 6 hours or less then the summarize works as expected. If the time range is 12 hours or higher the total reported by summarize is much smaller than expected.

It appears to me that if I try to sum for 1 a day period it is not retrieving all of the data points for the day so my data is much smaller than expected. I have not found any information on the grafana site that talks about how to change this behavior.

Thanks,
Louis

Answer (score 1):

It's not Grafana problem - you should set up your retention and aggregation in Graphite properly. Please check [Graphite documentation](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-carbon.html#storage-schemas-conf) or that [summary](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md).
I think you need to keep your points for at least 1 day unaggregated, so, if you sending your temperature once per minute, you should have `retention = 1m:1d, ...`

Comment: My retention is currently set to:
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:365,5m:5y so I have 1 minute data for an entire year. The aggregation is also set to default but I don't think it should apply in this case. It looks like there is some sort of aggregation going on as part of the summarize call.
~

Comment: You were absolutely correct, I was missing the 'd' for 365d. It looks like after adding that in it will work correctly. Thanks for the prod in the correct direction.